# Why is $x\ln|x|$ not differentiable at 0?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

My professor asked me to think of a function that is continuous from $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ whose derivative is not continuous. I thought of the function $f(x)=x\ln|x|, f(0)=0$ but was told it wasn't differentiable at 0. Could anyone show me why?

Comment: What is the derivative of $ln(x)$? What would it's value be at zero?

Comment: @peterwhy: derivatives have not to be continuous. $C^1$ functions are a subset of differentiable functions.

Comment: The derivative of $f$ is $\ln|x|+1$ and is defined for $x\ne0$. The function is not differentiable at $0$, however the derivative is continuous on its domain of definition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint**. As $x \to 0^+$,
$$
\frac{f(x)-0}{x-0}=\frac{x\ln x-0}{x}=\ln x \to -\infty
$$ which is not finite.

Comment: I realized this a little after asking the question. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome.